# Is there a way to check if a field violates particular constraint in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm currently working on the usual authentication mechanism which involves user name, and password. During creation of new user record, I want to check if it violates the unique constraint on the `userName` field. I could think of a few ways to go about it but I just want to know if there's some built-in feature that can do this.

Something like:

```
User user = getUserFromSomewhere()
if (user.validate(['userName'], ['unique'])) {
    //do stuff
} else {
    //handle validation error
}
```

In the `validate` method above, the first list is the list of fields, the next one is the list of constraints to check.

Comment: Can you define [uniqueness](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html) on the domain? Then grails will check for it on save `username unique: true`

Comment: Yeah I can do that, and what I actually want is a way to check that it's that very constraint that gets violated.